# How to adjust view size for iPad and iPhone 4S without storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, ipad

I don't know how to adjust view size for iPad and iPhone 4S without storyboard.

Is Auto layout used only in storyboard? Can't I set it by code?

And for example, if I make the game that has different things depends on the stage, using storyboard is not the right way I think...

Is there a good way to adjust view size for iPad and iPhone 4s without storyboard?

Comment: Yes, for sure it's possible, autolayout is used not only in storyboards, you can do it in code too, although it takes much more time. Of course it depends how looks your UI like, some views ( like table from0 UITableViewController ) take automatically the whole screen regardless the target device. Anyway, have a look at [Programmatically Creating Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH16-SW1)

Comment: Something is hinted at in your question - you used the word "game". Are you talking `SpriteKit`? If so, please tag this for that and I'd remove the iOS and Xcode tags. Truth is, using `UIKit` it's actually quite simple to declare auto layout in code (I rarely use Storyboards) but I believe SpriteKit does not use auto layout.

Comment: @dfd I don't use SpriteKit and talk about only sprite kit. Whatever I make any apps, I want to use auto layout or something like this without storyboard.

Comment: (1) In my eyes, there's not difference between SpriteKit and "sprite kit". While this may be a communication issue, it's important. SpriteKit can't use auto layout. (2) The answer supplied should let you know that YES, auto layout (using `UIViews`, not `SKViews`) is easily possible and gives you a good start at how to do it. (3) I guess the *specific* question I have for you is just that - what *specific* question or issue are you having?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll be careful of it. My issue is that I can't adjust the size of all objects for iPad and 4s without storyboard. When I search how to adjust the size of objects, many people say "Use auto layout with storyboard". But now I don't use storyboard (When I set objects, I write codes, not add objects on storyboard). Some people say "View size * 0.8 is good", but if I use this way and when I build my app on iPad, it shows a little small for iPad display. I want to show all objects on iPad and 4s like other type like 5s and SE. But I don't know how to solve this problem without storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is: Yes.

It is fairly straightforward to use autolayout without IB. But there are a number of steps involved.

Here's a quick example of setting a subview to be the same size at the main view in a viewController (could be in viewDidLoad(), viewWillAppear(), etc.)

```
self.view.addSubview(viewToAutosize)
viewToAutosize.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
viewToAutosize.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
viewToAutosize.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
viewToAutosize.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
viewToAutosize.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Some gotchas:

you need to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false on the view you wish to autosize.

you can't modify the constraints unless the view is already added as a subview (the view you are constraining against needs to be in the same view hierarchy -- see the first line of code above).

you have to activate the constraints manually. I have shown just one possible way to do it.

You should google auto "layout programmatically" (without the quotes) and pick a tutorial, video or apple documentation you are comfortable with to learn more.  There's a lot you can do with auto layout, and it is definitely the future, since more device sizes are being added all the time.